# Is there a way to return the opposite of this regular expression?

Tags: regex

Is there a way to return the opposite of this regular expression?

```
preg_match_all('/\p{Han}+/u', '道斯·麥克', $matches);
```

I want `$matches` to return an array containing the "·" character and not an array of the Chinese characters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the reverse class, `\P{Han}+`:

```
if (preg_match_all('/\P{Han}+/u', '道斯·麥克', $matches))
{
    print_r($matches[0]); // => Array ( [0] => · )
}
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/jv5KBh)

While `\p{Han}` matches all Chinese chars, `\P{Han}` matches any char other than those chars.

The same pertains to other Unicode property classes: for each `\p{X}` there is a reverse `\P{X}` class. `\p{L}` matches any Unicode letter and `\P{L}` matches any char but a Unicode letter. Cf. `\p{N}` (digits) - `\P{N}` (non-digits), `\p{S}` (symbols) - `\P{S}` (non-symbols), etc.

Comment: I didn't know that. That's very useful! Thanks! :)